# Where to find rospy functions documentations

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently going through the ROS tutorials, but I can't seem to find where rospy functions are documented (Not in the roswiki at least). Take for instance [this PubSub Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber), where should I go to find out what `rospy.Publisher` does, what are its arguments, and what output does it give?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269358/where-to-find-rospy-functions-documentations/) by [Frank Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/31663/frank-lee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[wiki/rospy](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy), top-right: *Package Links* → [Code API](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/rospy/html/).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2